# Use of regEx with multiple categories

Tags: google-classroom

I need to rotate the match through variables Cat1 to Catx as long as there is data for the Cat'x'. Whenever I do this this, it does not consider as a variable but the literal Cat4 or Cat5 instead of the variable Cat4 & Cat5 when I try to compile the new category label. Such as the following with i increasing until there is no value to the variable searched for .. i.e. Cat57 has nothing assigned.

```
    category = "Cat"+i
```

This is the portion of my code I believe that needs to be adjusted .. essentially based on the category I am going to assign it a specific column in my spreadsheet (this part hasn't been added yet) .. still stuck on the matching through multiple categories

```
      if(studentmarks && studentmarks.length > 0 && assign.maxPoints > 0){
     for (d = 0; d < studentmarks.length; d++){
       var marks = studentmarks[d];
    if(student.userId == marks.userId){
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url).getSheetByName(shet);


    var re = RegExp(Cat1);


    if (assign.title.match(re))
    ss.appendRow([category, assign.title, marks.assignedGrade, 
    assign.maxPoints]);
```

Comment: Show the code where you assign `CAT1` a value.

Comment: It's as simple as var Cat1 = "(A)"; var Cat2 = "(T)"; var Cat3 = "(C)"; ... also remember I will not exactly know these .. they will be user inputs for the different categories they wish to have.

Comment: So you have an x numbers of Cat variables? why don't you make it an array? It makes no sense to have multiple variables that represents the same stuff in the way you are describing. Could you maybe reveal more about your code including the definiton of the CAT? also what is exactly what you want? Maybe you don't need RegEx at all.

Comment: thank you .. I do not know why I haven't tried it in that manner.

Comment: I've added an answer to help anybody that stumbles upon this post. Feel free to modify/accept/critique it or create your own answer showing how you made your changes.

Answer (score 0):

As we have talked in the comments there is no need to actually use RegEx in this case.

Just define an array and iterate through. Without the need

```
// Define new array
var Cat = [];

//
// Do stuf to populate Cat array
//

//Access your data
for(var i = 0; i < Cat.length; i++){
  var element = Cat[i];
}
```